# how to be able to not return json in express in aws lambda and aws sam when using express.static

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, serverless

I am making a serverless website using aws lambda and the sma cli tool from aws (mostly just to test making real requests to the api). I want to serve assets with the express.static function, but have a problem. When i use it I get an error about it not returning json an the error says that it needs to do that to work. I have 2 functions for now: views (to serve the ejs files) and assets (to serve static files like css and frontend js). Here is my template.yml:

```yaml
# This is the SAM template that represents the architecture of your serverless application
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-template-basics.html

# The AWSTemplateFormatVersion identifies the capabilities of the template
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/format-version-structure.html
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  [Description goes here]

# Transform section specifies one or more macros that AWS CloudFormation uses to process your template
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-section-structure.html
Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

# Resources declares the AWS resources that you want to include in the stack
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html
Resources:
  assets:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: amplify/backend/function/assets/src/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 100
      Description: serves the assets
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /assets/{folder}/{file}
            Method: GET
  views:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: amplify/backend/function/views/src/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 100
      Description: serves the views
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: GET

Outputs:
  WebEndpoint:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

And my code for the assets function:
index.js:

```js
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const app = require('./app');

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);
  return awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
};
```

app.js:

```js
const express = require('express'),

    app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'))

app.listen(3000);

module.exports = app
```

Is there some config option for the template.yml that I should know or do I have to change my code?

Answer (score 0):

I made my own solution with fs in node js. I made a simple peice of code like this in the views function:

```js
app.get('/assets/*', (req, res) => {
    if (!fs.existsSync(__dirname + `/${req.url}`)) {
        res.sendStatus(404).send(`CANNOT GET ${req.url}`);
        return;
    }
    res.send(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + `/${req.url}`, 'utf-8'));
})
```

I also edited the template.yml to make it so the api with the path of /assets/{folder}/{file} is for the views function and deleted the assets function and move the assets folder with all the assets to the views function dir

EDIT:
For almost everything for some resson the content type http header is always being set text/html, but chnaging the code to this fixs it:

```js
app.get('/assets/*', (req, res) => {
    if (!fs.existsSync(`${__dirname}${req.url}`)) {
        res.sendStatus(404).send(`CANNOT GET ${req.url}`);
        return;
    }
    res.contentType(path.basename(req.url))
    res.send(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + `${req.url}`, 'utf-8'));
})
```

All this does is use the contentType function on the res object. You just pass in the name of the file and it will automatically find the right content type.